# .split(' ') Creating a blank line of input in Java

Tags: java

In the following code, I am attempting to split the following input into two strings which were originally separated by a space.

Input:

```
3413289830 a-bcdefghij
776 a+bc
```

Program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringOut
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File("C:\\test.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        String line;

        while (in.hasNextLine() == true)
        {
            line = in.nextLine();
            String parts[] = line.split(' ');
            System.out.println(parts[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3413289830

776
```

So, as you can see, a blank line will be outputted the second time the code inside the while is executed; this blank line is clearly coming from some code inside my while-loop scope, therefore, I can circumvent this error by adding

```
in.nextLine();
```

However, I would like to know where is this extra line coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this code compiled correctly? You have to use `line.split(" ")` with the double quotes.

Apart from that error, the code you wrote works perfectly with the input, with no extra blank line. I have tried it out.

Check your input file again.

Also `in.nextLine()` is required in any case, because `hasNextLine()` only checks if there are more lines to read.

Input:

```
3413289830 a-bcdefghij
776 a+bc
```

Program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringOut
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        String line;

        while (in.hasNextLine() == true)
        {
            line = in.nextLine();
            String parts[] = line.split(" ");
            System.out.println(parts[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3413289830
776
```

Comment: Yea whoops I just rewrote the file in the text box and placed the ' ' by accident, in the actual file it's " ", it appears that the input in my text file has an extra space at the end of each line although if you hit the left-arrow key it will stay at the same position and not move to the next line till you hit it again, hopefully that makes sense. Also there's already an in.nextLine() at the start of the while section.

Comment: I have added the exact code and input that is working for me. Also, like I said, `in.nextLine()` is required anyway, otherwise you cannot read the file. It is perfectly fine. There must be something else wrong with your input file.

Comment: `hasNextLine()` only checks if there are more lines. It does not read the line.

Comment: yea my input file somehow has an invisible char at the end of each line that represents a blank line which is why my output is different.

Comment: You might have to recreate the file then, for consistency. Or you can add a workaround in the code to check for `\n` after a space.

Answer (score -2):

You have to change

```
System.out.println(parts[0]);
```

to

```
System.out.print(parts[0]);
```

as println() will print a new line (ln) after it gets executed.